# Failure to compare values when I am reading from CSV file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, sharepoint

My PowerShell script is as follows, I have got all the sites in farm saved as CSV file using `Export-Csv` command.

```
$farmList  = Import-Csv "TestFarm.csv"
$farmList1 = Import-Csv "OtherFarm1.csv"
foreach ($site in $farmList)  
{
    Write-Host "db - ", $site
    foreach ($farmsite in $farmList1) 
    {
        if ($site -eq $farmsite) {
            Write-Host "matching site found for ", $farmsite
            break
        }
        Write-Host "farm - ", $farmsite
    }
}
```

My Excel files in CSV looks like

```
Site
/sites/TestSite
/sites/testsite1234
...
```

The second Excel file in CSV looks like

```
Site
/sites/TestSite
/sites/testsite1234
...
```

When I debug the program, I am getting a value of `$site` and `$farmSite` as
`@{Site=/sites/TestSite}` , but when I compare the values using `-eq`, the values do not match.

I have also tried using `Compare-Object` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the objects' `Site` properties instead of the objects themselves.

Change this:

```
if ($site -eq $farmsite) {
```

into this:

```
if ($site.Site -eq $farmsite.Site) {
```

If the files contain just this one property you could also expand it on import:

```
$farmList  = Import-Csv "TestFarm.csv" | Select-Object -Expand Site
$farmList1 = Import-Csv "OtherFarm1.csv" | Select-Object -Expand Site
```

The latter would also allow you to simplify your code by using a `-contains` check:

```
foreach ($farmsite in $farmList1) {
    if ($farmList -contains $farmsite) {
        Write-Host "matching site found for $farmsite"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar , I came to the same conclusion after looking at the csv structure. I liked your suggestion on contains, That will greatly simplify my code.